# Is there a way to shorten branch names in git commands?

Tags: git, git-branch

When I work on a bigger project, I use long branch names, eg. `dev/username/PROJECT-JIRANUM_some_description`.
It would be cool to be able to do sth like this:

```
git branch -D STH(xxxx)
```

Where STH() is some syntax that would use some glob-like matching of branch names (so that xxxx could be a JIRA number contained in branch name). If there is ambiguity, git would inform and abort the command.

It sth like this is possible at the moment? I could not find any information on this.

Comment: Most shells support tab completion for git branches, try pressing tab 2 times halfway a branch name

Comment: You could just rename the branch to be shorter.

Comment: @ferrybig: That's not helping in my case, as I have many branches within the same project, even JIRA numbers are dubling. So I would have to go through the process of tab -> write sth -> tab etc several times, wheras giving some unique part of the name from the *end* of the branchname would do the trick.

Comment: @poke: That's not a possibility when you have certain naming conventions project-wide

Comment: But branch names are local only. You can name them whatever you want in your local repository without affecting other shared repositories.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) with [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/)  since it gives you branch name completion as follows:
('...' appears every time I press tab for branch name completion)

[image]

If you go down this route, for reference here is the list of prezto modules I've enabled (in `~/.zpreztorc`):

```
# Set the Prezto modules to load (browse modules).
# The order matters.
zstyle ':prezto:load' pmodule \
  'environment' \
  'terminal' \
  'editor' \
  'history' \
  'archive' \
  'directory' \
  'spectrum' \
  'utility' \
  'completion' \
  'ssh' \
  'git' \
  'history-substring-search' \
  'prompt'
```

I believe the important ones (for what you need) are utility, completion and git

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Sadly, there seems not to be a bash equivalent, but maybe this will encourage me to switch shells.
Also, I am working on windows which makes things a little bit more difficult.

Comment: Oh yes please. Please spend a couple of days with Zsh (+Prezto), trust me you won't go back!  For what it's worth, I was using zsh happily on Cygwin in Windows and barely had any issues (only some chars wouldn't display in the prompt, when using specific PROMPT themes from prezto, not an issue really).  The one thing that got me the motivation to go through the motivation was seamless history syncing across multiple sessions that comes out of the box in zsh but is a hack at the best for bash!  + lots of uber-cool stuff like https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search !!

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to rename you branches to something that is short and easy to remember for you `git branch -m <oldname> <newname>`.

Otherwise you should enable git-completion, if do not already have. See git http://code-worrier.com/blog/autocomplete-git/. This way you can simply use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to auto complete your branch names.

Comment: Unfortunately autocomplete-git works like a normal completion, it doesn't have the characteristics I described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since git branches are actually movable labels, locally you may name them as you wish. The only actual need is to follow your project conventions when you push your changes back to a central repo. For your convenience you may [configure](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) branch specific fetch- and push- settings (check those `branch.<name>....` settings) to automatically map your branch on `fetch`, `merge` and `push`.

Comment: This seems to be really inconvenient to do such configuration per branch.

Comment: well. if you have a given naming convention, then, probably, you have a rule to simplify, rewrite branch name automatically. So you may simply put a single rewriting rule for all remote branches.